# Shorewall: VPN clients can access LAN resources, but not the Internet

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn, gateway, shorewall

I set up a network in my studio's office with a Raspberry Pi serving as a VPN server for remote clients to access LAN resources.

Router port-forwards 1194 port to RPi, so it's accessible from the Internet.

After some time, I successfully set up OpenVPN with Shorewall to grant VPN clients access to selected LAN servers. But for some reason, VPN clients can't access Internet at all.

Here's my Shorewall setup:

I set up my three zones in **zones**, **interfaces** and **host** files.

**zones**

```
#ZONE   TYPE
fw      firewall
net     ipv4
loc:net ipv4
vpn     ipv4
```

**interfaces**

```
#ZONE   INTERFACE   OPTIONS
net     eth0        dhcp,tcpflags,nosmurfs,routefilter,logmartians,sourceroute=0
vpn     tun0
```

**hosts**

```
#ZONE           HOSTS
loc             eth0:192.168.200.0/24 (LAN subnet)
```

There's an entry in **tunnels** file for OpenVPN server:

**tunnels**

```
#TYPE           ZONE    GATEWAY
openvpnserver   net     0.0.0.0/0
```

Packets from VPN to eth0 are masqueraded, since the default gateway for LAN clients is the router, not RPi.

**masq**

```
#INTERFACE      SOURCE                      ADDRESS
eth0            10.8.0.0/24 (VPN subnet)    192.168.200.54 (local RPi address)
```

**policy** rejects connections from vpn to loc and accepts connections from vpn to net. Specific connections from vpn to loc are accepted in **rules** file.

What did I miss? Why VPN clients can't access Internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not in Shorewall config at all. There actually WAS access from VPN to the Internet, but VPN clients had wrong DNS server address.

There was a line in OpenVPN's **server.conf**

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.1"
```

Which didn't make sense in given setup. I corrected the address, and now VPN clients do have access to the Internet.